# Using datatype boolean for publish and unpublished in mysql

Tags: php, web, mysqli, content-management-system

`<select>`
`<option>`Publish`</option>`
`<option>`unPublish`</option>`
`</select>`

mysql column name "Status" 
Datatype "Boolean"

I want to set this when i select publish. Category visible on my web page and when i select unpublished category disable from my webpage.

can any one send me a "php code" how to set process page and mysql column

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['published'])) {

    $conn = getConnection();

    if(! $conn ) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $published_value = (isset($_POST['published'])) ? 1 : 0;

    $sql = '
        UPDATE table_name
        SET published='.(int) $published_value.'
        WHERE record_id = 1
    ';

    mysql_close($conn);
}

function getConnection() {

    $dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'rootpassword';

    return mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
}

function executeSQL($sql) {
    mysql_select_db('your_db_name');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(!$retval) {
        die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thx buddy its helpful . but i use this code Boolean value 0,1 bolth catefory showing on may webpage.